# Docker Compose - How reference many schemas in one mysql container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, flyway

I'm trying to use two schemas into one mysql container. I have two flyway services that connect to two different schemas. The .yml file of Docker Compose looks like:

```
version: '2'

services:

mysqldb:
image: mysql:5.6.26
environment:
  MYSQL_USER: user
  MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
  MYSQL_DATABASE:
  - my
  - my_post
ports:
  - "3306:3306"

 flyway-service1-i:
image: mik/flyway-service
volumes:
 - "../resources/db/migration:/migrations/ro"
depends_on:
 - mysqldb
links:
 - mysqldb
command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mi -user=user -password=password -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations='filesystem:/migrations'

flyway-service2-i:
image: mialk/flyway-post-service
volumes:
 - "../../../service2/src/main/resources/db/migration:/migrations/ro"
depends_on:
 - mysqldb
links:
 - mysqldb
command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mi_post -user=user -password=password -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations='filesystem:/migrations'
```

But when I run the command sudo docker-compose up the terminal show this message:

**ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.mysqldb.environment.MYSQL_DATABASE contains ["mialquiler", "mialquiler_post"], which is an invalid type, it should be a string, number, or a null**

I traid without specifying MYSQL_DATABASE property, but it didn't work.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MYSQL_DATABASE` variable allows a single database to be created, and permissions granted on the database to the `MYSQL_USER` if specified.

You can use a single database to house multiple schema's.

If you need to create multiple databases you may need to run some custom SQL as flyway can't do database creation for you. The [flyway test resources include a mysql example](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/test/resources/migration/dbsupport/mysql/createDatabase.sql).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer @Matt  :) . So, I can use flyway in the .yml file in this way for example: 

**command: migrate -url=jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/mi_post -user=user -password=password -eschemas=my_post_schema1 -baselineOnMigrate=true -locations='filesystem:/migrations'**

Thanks! :D